# How can i process the data after '/ ' in url with out treating it as directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, web-services

I am trying to make an url shortening web app in which i want to process the data after / without treating it as directory?
for example,
www.tinyurl.com/jf8Qa 
i want to get the value jf8Qa and process it ,but my apache web server is treating it as a directory .Instead i want to get the value after / and process it.
please help me out.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a .HTACCESS file with RewriteEngine On.

create a file in the root directory named .htaccess (just .htaccess, nothing else!) - if it already exists, add this to the bottom.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+) /index.php?params=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note: Untested - but should work!
In your index.php file $_GET['params'] will contain the value of whatever you've got after the domain.

Be sure to check it's set before using it, this will allow you to serve different content to users that haven't entered the small key after the domain.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do a `.htaccess` rewrite like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|images|robots\\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The file (literally named `.htaccess`) would go in your root directory (or whatever directory you want this to be effected in). This is just a basic example. This should re-route all requests to your your `index.php` page for processing. The effects are felt throughout all the child directories until it hits a new `.htaccess` file if any are found in the child folders.

Here is an ugly-a$$ site, but it helped me out a lot: http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php